# Typeclass instance inheritance in Scala

Tags: scala, typeclass

I am translating the Haskell code in https://sebfisch.github.io/haskell-regexp/regexp-play.pdf in Scala for self study.
I translated "class Semiring" (page 2) in this way:

```
  trait Semiring[S] {
    def zero: S
    def one: S
    def add(a: S, b: S): S
    def mult(a: S, b: S): S
  }
```

and the related class SemiringI (page 7) in this way:

```
  trait SemiringI[S] extends Semiring[S] {
    def index: Int => S
  }
```

I had then to provide instances for specific type parameters, so I tried to proceed in what I think is the canonical way, i.e., defining them as implicit vals.

```
  implicit val semiringLeftmost = new Semiring[LeftmostT] {
    // ...implementation of zero, one, add, mult...
  }
```

However, I had some problems when I had to define a SemiringI instance for LeftmostT:

```
  implicit val semiringILeftmost = new SemiringI[LeftmostT] {
    // ...implementation of zero, one, add, mult (same as for Semiring[LeftmostT])
    // ...implementation of index
  }
```

It seemed to me I had to repeat the implementations of the functions already defined in Semiring[LeftmostT], that, of course, would not have been scalable.
I searched the web for answers, but I was not able to find them.
For example, in https://www.slideshare.net/jdegoes/scalaz-8-a-whole-new-game (slide 7) MonoidInt does not reuse the definition of append from Semigroup, as I expected.

At the end, I managed to find a way to proceed, namely:

```
  // traits Semiring[S] and SemiringI[S] defined as above

  class semiringLeftmostC extends Semiring[LeftmostT] {
        // ...implementation of zero, one, add, mult...
  }
  implicit val semiringLeftmost = new semiringLeftmostC()

  class semiringILeftmostC extends semiringLeftmostC with SemiringI[LeftmostT] {
        // ...implementation of index
  }

  implicit val semiringILeftmost = new semiringILeftmostC()
```

but I am not sure it is the best one.
Can someone please explain to me whether there are other possibilities to reach the same goals, i.e., reusing code in hierarchies of typeclass instances?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://typelevel.org/blog/2016/09/30/subtype-typeclasses.html

Comment: Given you went the subtype route, the simplest solution would be to only implement the **most specific** typeclass _(`SemiringI` in your case)_. - That way you only need to implement all one time, and it will work whenever you ask for it or for any of its parents.

Comment: @DmytroMitin: that article discusses problems in typeclass lattice hierarchies. If it also solves my problem is not evident to me.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: it seems to me that with your proposal I cannot use only Semiring if I need to. A concrete example of what you have in mind would be helpful.

Comment: @LoneKnight73 Sorry, I did not understand your comment. But answering what I believe you asked. For example if `Monoid[T] extends Semigroup[T]` and you have `implicit IntMonoid: Monoid[Int] = ...` and you ask for `implicitly[Semigroup[Int]]` it will find the **IntMonoid**, after all a `Monoid` is also a `Semirgoup`. - That is what I proposed to you, only implement the most concrete possible typeclass, and you will have all of its parents in scope too. - Was I clear or did I miss something?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: ok, sorry, I did not think that Monoid[Int] could have been used in place of Semigroup[Int]. It still seems to me this is somehow inconvenient: when I extend, say, SemiringI, does it mean I have to move all the implementations to the new class?

Comment: @LoneKnight73 no worries. So, does that solves your problem?

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: honestly not (see my previous comment)

Comment: @LoneKnight73 Sorry, I miss that part _(maybe you added it in a edit and I read it before?)_. I do not understand what you mean with _"I have to move all the implementations to the new class"_? - There is no new class, just one `implicit val semiringILeftmost:SemiringI[LeftmostT] = new SemiringI[LeftmostT]  { ... }`. And yes, you will implement everything there, but only there. You should not have more implicits related to `LeftmostT` and the `SemiringI` hierarchy-

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: yes, sorry, I hit newline before the comment was complete. Trying to explain my concern a bit better: suppose you want to extend SemiringI with SemiringNew (i.e. `trait SemiringNew[S] extends SemiringI[S]`). My understanding is that, in this case, you have to move all the implementations to SemiringNew[LeftmostT] (but maybe I am wrong). If this is the case, I don't think this is a satisfactory solution, because it forces you to rewrite already existing code to extend it.

Comment: @LoneKnight73 yes you are right. However, usually you are not creating new typeclases very frequently. But, if that is your requirement then yes, using the subtype encoding may not work for you. You may try with the encoding that the link provided by Dmytro in the very first comment suggest.

Comment: @LuisMiguelMejíaSuárez: I read that article but I was not able to understand it. Thanks for your suggestions, anyway.

Comment: @LoneKnight73 What the article says is that, instead of saying `Monoid[T] extends Semigroup[T]` you can say `Monoid[T] { def semigroup: Semigroup[T] }` meaning having **Monoid** implies having a **Semigroup** too. Then you can do this `implicit val IntMonoid = new Monoid[Int] { def semigroup = implicitly }`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [this post](https://contributors.scala-lang.org/t/encoding-type-class-hierarchies/4626/14), and the advent of Scala 3, I was able to write a concise version of the class hierarchy:

```
  trait Semiring[S] {
    def zero: S
    def one: S
    def add(a: S, b: S): S
    def mult(a: S, b: S): S
  }

  trait SemiringI[S] extends Semiring[S] {
    def index(i: Int): S
  }

  given semiringLeftmost: Semiring[LeftmostT] with {
    // implementation of Semiring functions
  }

  given semiringILeftmost: SemiringI[LeftmostT] with {
    export semiringLeftmost.*
    override def index(i: Int): LeftmostT = ??? // actual implementation not relevant
  }
```

I can infer by the mentioned post, however, that there seems to be no consensus on how to encode typeclass hierarchies in Scala 3. The official documentation  examples I found seem to redefine functions in the derived traits (https://dotty.epfl.ch/docs/reference/contextual/type-classes.html).